# How to show list of taxonomy terms associated with specific post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom post type named "`football_team`" and this custom post has a post named Barcelona with id "post=7".
I am using `single-football_team.php`  template to show this post as:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content-parts/content', 'team' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

In `content-parts/content-team.php` file I am using following codes:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'competition', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );
?>
<?php
foreach( $terms as $term ) {?>
  <section class="achievement-section clearfix">
    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <div class=" league-and-season clearfix">
    <div class="honour-league-name"> <?php echo $term->name; ?> </div>
      <?php
      $team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_team_team_name', true );
      $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'football_league',
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
          'taxonomy' => 'competition',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $term
          ), 
        ),          
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'football_league_team_name',
              'value' => $team,
              'compare' => '='          
            ),
        ),
      );

    $fixture_query = null;
    $fixture_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
      <div class="honour-season-name">
        <ul >
            <?php while ( $fixture_query->have_posts() ) : $fixture_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
            $champion_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_league_team_name', true );
            $terms_competition = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' );
            $terms_season = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'season' ); ?>
                <?php 
                      foreach ($terms_season as $object) {?>
                       <li> <?php echo  $object->name; ?></li> 
                      <?php } 
                   ?>
                <?php $counter++; ?>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="achievement-times"><span><?php echo $counter; ?> </span></div>
  </section> 
<?php }
?>
```

In the above codes following line is the metabox of team name of `football_team` custom post:

`$team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_team_team_name', true )`;

**AND**

---

### Above codes shows following:[image: Taxonomy]

But the problem is:

1. PREMIER LEAGUE
2. BUNDESLIGA
3. ITALIAN SERIE A

Above three Competition taxonomy terms are not associated with the post no:7(Barcelona).
I think it showing all the terms due to get_term function and foreach loop.Is there any way to fetch only specific taxonomy term associated the post=7 or Barcelona? 
Any solution would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I used following codes and it is working perfectly.

```
<?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'competition'); ?>
<?php
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ) {
foreach( $terms as $term ) {?>
  <section class="achievement-section clearfix">
    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <div class=" league-and-season clearfix">
    <div class="honour-league-name"> <?php echo $term->name; ?> </div>
      <?php
      $team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_team_team_name', true );
      $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'football_league',
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
          'taxonomy' => 'competition',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $term
          ), 
        ),          
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'football_league_team_name',
              'value' => $team,
              'compare' => '='          
            ),
        ),
      );

    $fixture_query = null;
    $fixture_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
      <div class="honour-season-name">
        <ul >
            <?php while ( $fixture_query->have_posts() ) : $fixture_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
            $champion_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_league_team_name', true );
            $terms_competition = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' );
            $terms_season = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'season' ); ?>
                <?php 
                      foreach ($terms_season as $object) {?>
                       <li> <?php echo  $object->name; ?></li> 
                      <?php } 
                   ?>
                <?php $counter++; ?>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="achievement-times"><span><?php echo $counter; ?> </span></div>
  </section> 
<?php }
}
?>
```

[image]